# Using Mathematical Induction prove that: $r+r^2+r^3+...+r^n=\frac{r(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ ,where $r≠1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am trying to prove a mathematical expression using **Mathematical Induction**. How to solve **LHS** of the equation to result **RHS**:

> $$LHS=\frac{r(1-r^k)}{1-r}+r^{k+1}$$
>   $$RHS=\frac{r(1-r^{k+1})}{1-r}$$

Original Question is as follows:

> Using Mathematical Induction prove that:
>   $$r+r^2+r^3+...+r^n=\frac{r(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$
>   Where $r≠1$

And is it a geometric series?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{r(1-r^k)}{1-r}+r^{k+1}$ for the LHS?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
r+r^2+ \cdots+r^n +\color{red}{r^{n+1}} =\frac{r(1-r^{n})}{1-r} +\color{red}{\frac{r^{n+1}-r^{n+2}}{1-r} }= \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Exactly, I need to edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{r(1-r^k)}{1-r}+r^{k+1}=\frac{r-r^{k+1}+r^{k+1}-r^{k+2}}{1-r}=\frac{r(1-r^{k+1})}{1-r}$$

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.